# how to debug paypal payment method

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal-express

I want check what is the request paypal sending at a time of placing order. and what is the response getting. because i got a error invalid token #10410. when i try to place order using paypal payment method.

Comment: Please enable debug mode "Yes" in admin side : System->Configuration ->Payment Methods (Basic Settings - PayPal Express Checkout) and error log see in folder (\var\log)

Answer (score 2):

**1. If you place the order via PayPal (make the payment)**

Go to `System > Configuration > Payment Methods > PayPal [...] > Advanced Settings > Debug Mode > Yes`

If Debug is enabled you'll find the request/response in `var/log/payment_[method name].log`

**2. If you only get forwarded to Paypal and want to look into the request data (did not finish payment)**

Go to `Mage_Paypal_Model_Api_Nvp` and edit `public function call($methodName, array $request)`

Add some logging code like

```
Mage::log(print_r($request,true),true,"paypal_debugging.log");
```

You'll find the file in `var/log`