# Why Paypal gateway has rejected request error comes (Error No.10413) in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal

**The error is displayed as follows:**

> PayPal gateway has rejected request. The totals of the cart item
>   amounts do not match order amounts (#10413: Transaction refused
>   because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for
>   details).

Comment: https://www.paypal.com/us/smarthelp/article/why-did-i-get-error-10413-%E2%80%9Ctransaction-refused-because-of-an-invalid-argument.-see-additional-error-messages-for-details.-the-totals-of-the-cart-item-amounts-do-not-match-order-amounts%E2%80%9D-ts1990 and https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88640/how-to-debug-paypal-payment-method/#answer-222589

Answer (score 1):

> Go to Admin panel locate navigation System >> Configuration >> Sales
>
> > > Payment Method >> Choose Paypal (exiting Paypal method which enable in fronted for example Payments Pro (Includes Express Checkout)) >>
> > >       find "Transfer Cart Line Items" choose option value : No

Comment: thanks for you answer but i tried already this is not working @Charlie

Comment: Still Not working @Abhinav Singh

Comment: set transfer cart item line to no but not work

Comment: In my case, i activated 'SSL verification' and was not checked 'Transfer Cart Line Items'.

Now, I activated this opcion in Module Paypal - Configuration - Basic Settings and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Admin Panel > Store > Configuration > Sales Payment Method > Choose PayPal* (existing PayPal method which enable in fronted for example Payments Standard)

1. Email Associated with PayPal Merchant Account -> It should be valid PayPal Merchant Account.
2. API Username -> It should be valid API Username.
3. API Password -> It should be API Password.
4. API Signature -> It should be API Signature.
5. Enable this Solution -> It should be Yes.

**Note:** All above filed should be valid credentials.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old but I just had the same issue integrating PayPal in Magento 2.4.5 instance.

In my case, **the issue was in the address** of the customer I was using to place the test orders.

**Make sure the address doesn't have weird characters** :)